# It is possible to hide the Request URL from in the Chrome web inspector network tab?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a website in the AngularJS, and I have a problem regarding a security issue. The API URL is visible in the Request header section.

[image]

In the above screenshot, the Request URL is shown, and I need to hide this URL. I have tried searching different sites with different keywords and I can't find any solutions regarding to this issue.

Is possible to hide the URL from the header section of Chrome browser network tab in AngularJS?

Comment: Why do you need to hide this URL? I doubt you will be able to. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/360627). If you could hide this, what would stop a malicious person from creating a website that makes "hidden" requests to other pages?

Comment: sir our website is ready but at teaster point of view it is a bug that's the reason, ir is possible to hide it?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a bug to me, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do

Comment: sir i am also said it is not a bug but he is not agree.tell m sir it is possible to hide it?

Comment: I would ask him why it is a bug...

Comment: sir he said that anyboby can open the chorme and copy the URL?

Comment: @Roman — So? That still isn't a bug. That's a fundamental feature of how the WWW works.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The longer answer is - you can obfuscate it by hitting another URL first, but of course *that* URL will be visible.

This is the web - you can't hide anything that your running on the client's browser.

Comment: Even if you obfuscate using another URL, someone could still get the API url using a tool like Wireshark.

Comment: Yep - I was literally typing that. Like, if Chrome had some support for: window.hideUrls=[ array of stuff to hide], well hell, then it would be in view source. ;) But yes, I could simply run Wireshark to see it.

Comment: And if chrome _could_ do that, I probably wouldn't use Chrome anyways since that could potentially be a security issue.

Comment: @RaymondCamden and GrumpyCrouton finally thank you  sir for his useful information.finally it is possible to hide from the network tab i m right sir?

Comment: @Roman It is not possible.

Comment: ok sir thaks.. it is possible to send URL via encrypted format it is not easily readable ?

Comment: Are you asking if you can encrypt the URL? No. You can't hit foo.com w/o the user knowing it.

Comment: Ok sir.it is possible if we have know which user is logged in currently?

Comment: Logged in to the local machine - logged in to the web app? That's a totally different topic.

Comment: Sir i am talking about web app

Comment: Then the logged in user is typically handed via a session and your web app.